# How to link multiple subdomains to one Google Page for rel="publisher"

Tags: google-plus

For my website AglaSem i have 6-7 subdomains for different sections. I tried to link all of them with my google+ page as publisher. However i noticed that the only url which i added on gogole+ page profile as website works for rel="publisher" and not any other.

It shows the error:

> This is not a verified publisher markup.

Is there any way i can link all subdomains to same google+ page as its not convent to make google+ pages for each one of them.